# How probable is the event?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

QUESTION:

The length of time in minutes for an individual to be served at a local restaurant is the outcome of a random variable, T, having a mean of 6 and a variance of 1.5. How probable is the event that an individual will be served within 3 to 9 minutes?

MY APPROACH:

I first thought of applying chebysev's inequality but failed in my approach.

Comment: Can you clarify what "failed" means here?

Comment: the separation between the mean and the required values (3 and 9) that is 3 couldn't be represented in terms of C x S.D(where c is any  real number)

Comment: Why is that?  Why isn't $c=\frac3{\sqrt{1.5}}$?

Comment: How do you think that Chebysev's inequality fails?  Works perfectly for me ...

Comment: yes sorry I had done a silly mistake,chebysev's works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

I think (and underline this is only my humble opinion...) there's is a high probability that your exercise requires to assume normality...

Thus

$$P(3<T<9)=\Phi(\frac{9-6}{\sqrt{1.5}})-\Phi(\frac{3-6}{\sqrt{1.5}})=\Phi(2.45)-\Phi(-2.45)=0.993-0.007=98.6\%$$

Comment: While this may well have been the intended answer, the variable is always positive so cannot actually be normal.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime : also if the variable is always positive it can be normal...it depends on its parameters...if the mean is 6 and the variance 1.5 the values cannot be less than $\mu-3.3\sigma$

Comment: The pdf of a normal random variable is $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp((x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2)$, which is positive everywhere on $\mathbb R$, no matter what the parameters are.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime :yes, of course. But we are evaluating a % so for a $X \sim N(6;1.5)$ the probability $P(X<0)\approx 4.8\times 10^{-7}\rightarrow 0.00\%$

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $\to 0$. That probability is a number, not a sequence, so it doesn't tend to anything. In fact it is $0.0032\%$ (to 2 sig fig).

Comment: @EspeciallyLime : with $\rightarrow 0$ I simply mean that the value is very close to zero...and evaluating a % it is usual to consider zero any value like 0.0002, 0.000x and so on....anyway you are right... next time I will avoid to answer to questions like this...have a nice day

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your answer, and I wouldn't want to put you off making similar answers in future. I merely thought it was worth commenting that this assumption, which might well have been the intended one, can't be completely accurate. I apologise if I came across as rude, and wish you a nice day too.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime : no problem! I perfectly know what you are pointing out and I totally agree with you...next time I will be more precise in my comments